# Inconveniente con el hosting gratuito StackOverFlow

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7, hosting

Hola cordial saludo les escribe Hernán Martínez desde Colombia, espero
que se encuentren bien, quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño aplicativo web haciendo uso de las siguientes
herramientas:
Php-Mysql(Phpmyadmin) Ajax, el aplicativo tiene como objeto mostrar registros de acuerdo
a un artista seleccionado, dicho desarrollo se expone en el siguiente sitio web, para ello tengo la siguiente prueba piloto:

http://clasicotk.epizy.com/Artista.php

Hoy 14 de Marzo de 2022 a las 11:00 de la mañana me funcionaba correctamente
el apLicativo (con decir que me funcionaba correctamente quiere decir que al seleccionar
un registro del combobox o cuadro combinado me traía de manera adecuada los datos correspondientes
al registro seleccionado), salí a almorzar a las 12:00 M, con la felicidad de que todo estaba funcionando bien (aunque no es un aplicativo del otro mundo hacia lo que tiene que hacer).
Llegue de almorzar a las 13:00 horas y voy a realizar exactamente lo que estaba funcionando bien a las 11:00 de la mañana (con el objeto de incluir mas cosas a mi pequeño desarrollo)
y desafortunadamente no sirve (es decir solo me sirve  el cargue de registros de artistas en el combobox, pero no me muestra en la tabla los datos correspondientes al artista seleccionado).

estoy utilizando el servidor infinityfree con cuenta gratuita, pues para el pequeño desarrollo que necesito no veo conveniente pagar un hosting de pago y además no dispongo de los medios en este momento para contratar uno.

Ya para finalizar mi pregunta es: El problema es que estoy trabajando bajo modalidad de hosting gratuito??, será que el hosting no soporta el código de los lenguajes en los que tengo desarrollado mi microaplicativo??, cosa que me parece extraña puesto que en un momento si me sirvió y después no.

muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar

Att. Hernán Martínez.

Comment: ¿Esto es una pregunta o un relato?

Comment: Lo primero deberías pasar por la sección [ask], lo segundo, si abres tu web y muestras la consola, verás un error 500, por lo que seguro tienes algún problema dentro del php que no te está terminando de funcionar

Comment: Señores Mauricio Contreras y Oscar Novas no es nada agradable venir aquí a preguntar por cosas que no deberían de estar sucediendo  es decir cosas que funcionan bien y después de repente no funcionen "por que si", en ese orden de ideas las preguntas que se hacen aquí no solo tienen que ver con código sino con inconvenientes en el posicionamiento de un sitio web, ya para terminar les comento que no soy nuevo aquí en StackOverflow y pese a que tengo necesidad nadie tiene que asumir que esta obligado a responder en este sitio así de que  si no tienen nada útil que aportar, mejor no opinen nada.

Comment: Martin.. entiendo que llevas un tiempo aqui. Pero lo que te estan remarcando, es totalmente valido. Tu pregunta, en si, no dice nada. El titulo, es muy raro y poco descriptivo de tu problema. Te recomendaria yo tambien pasar por [ask].. Realmente no me queda claro como queres que te ayuden (si me queda claro que tenes un problema, y si esta claro que alguien ya te dijo cual es)...